# How to get an attribute of an element based on the text in cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

(USING CHEERIO)I want to get the value of the element that includes the text "9" between the option tags:

```
<option value="19437843939456"> 8.5 </option>

<option value="19437843972224"> 9 </option>
```

I want to get this: `19437843972224` which is the value of the `value` attribute in the option tag

How would I get that with Cheerio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Select the option by using `$("option")`
>
> Adding the `:contains('string')` to the selector will look for the text of the option.
>
> Finally the `val()` method will get the value of the option.

Combine them to get the desired result:

```
$("option:contains('9')").val();
```

Here's a [working example](https://repl.it/repls/FriendlyLowGuiltware).

Check the [documentation](https://cheerio.js.org/) for more information.

**Update**

You need to use the correct `select` element, you can do it by using its `name` property:

```
$("select[name=id] option:contains('9')").val();
```

A more complex [example](https://repl.it/repls/DelightfulEnragedMineral).

Comment: I see you edited this, but I am still getting undefined.

Comment: Have you tried the example I linked? Maybe there's another issue?

Comment: Try using this link as the html and search for the html value= attribute I posted on the original question above (view-source:https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear/products/nkcu9180-101)

Comment: Your example gave me undefined when running it too lol.

Comment: Well then how am I supposed to get it?

Comment: You should add headers to your request (which is not in the question) to emulate the browser.

Comment: So proper headers will do the job?

Because I have accept, accept-language, and user-agent already

Comment: and I am able to log the body just fine

Comment: Check in text editor if you can find the value you need

Comment: oh! I just got it to say The value you need is: 9

But I need the value inside the option tag: 19437843972224

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220281/discussion-between-salvatore-timpani-and-tamas-szoke).